# How to vectorize more than one vector in Julia?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, julia

I want to write vectorized style code in Julia in the context of wanting to define a function which takes more than one vector as arguments like below.

[code]

```
using PyPlot;
m=[453 21 90;34 1 44;13 553 66]
a = [1,2,3]
b=[1,2,3]
f(x,y) = m[x,y]
f.(a,b)

#= expected result
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 453   21  90
  34    1  44
  13  553  66
#
```

[real result]

```
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 453
   1
  66
```

The dot notation only picks the first element of each row, ignoring the others, and makes a vector with just 3 elements instead of 3 x 3 matrix.

How can I write to get the expected result?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the two vectors needs to be a row vector so that Julia understands what you want to do, this simple example should help you understand Julia broadcasting:

```
julia> [1,2,3] .+ [10,20,30] # both have the same dimensions
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 11
 22
 33

julia> [1,2,3]' .+ [10,20,30] 
# first has dimensions (1,3) and second (3,1) => result is dimension (3,3)
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 11  12  13
 21  22  23
 31  32  33
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for

```
julia> f.(a, b')
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 453   21  90
  34    1  44
  13  553  66
```

Note the relevant section in the documentation for `broadcast` (type `?broadcast` into a REPL session to access it):

> Singleton and missing dimensions are expanded to match the extents of the other arguments by virtually repeating the value.

`a` is treated as a 3x1 matrix (but has the type `Vector{T}`), while `b'` is used as a 1x3 matrix (with the type `Adjoint(T, Vector{T})`). These are broadcast to the resulting 3x3 matrix.

When using `a` and `b` directly, no expansion of dimensions is necessary, and you'll end up with a 3x1 matrix.

Comment: Thank you. I got it. Understanding Julia just by reading official documentation is hard work for me.